# apachectl - doubts regular expression

Tags: linux, apache, awk, sed, systemctl

How do I get just status of the `apachectl` status command?

For example, in the output below, I just want to take the word "running"

```
Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago
```

I managed to get uptime with the command:

```
apachectl status | sed -n '/ ago $ / p' | sed 's /. \ {62 \} //'
```

However, I couldn't adapt this command to just get the status.

Comment: `apachectl status | sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/p'`

Comment: I added an answer with the `sed` solution to your regex problem, no need to know how specific app works.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually do this in this fashion. `is-active` is the accurate command to get the status of systemctl services.

```
[[ $(sudo systemctl is-active test.service) == "active" ]] && echo "Running." || echo "NOT runnnig."
```

OR more clearly:

```
[[ $(sudo systemctl is-active test.service) == "active" ]]\
&& echo "Running." || echo "NOT runnnig."
```

OR as per Ed sir's comment more safer option will be using usual `if` and `else` option as follows.

```
if [[ $(sudo systemctl is-active test.service) == "active" ]]
then
    echo "Running."
else
    echo "NOT runnnig."
fi
```

From man page of systemctl:

> is-active PATTERN... Check whether any of the specified units are
>   active (i.e. running). Returns an exit code 0 if at least one is
>   active, or non-zero otherwise. Unless --quiet is specified, this will
>   also print the current unit state to standard output.

Comment: be careful with `test && do_a || do_b` - that's not a ternary construct like it looks like, the `||` is testing for the last command executed failing so if `test` resulted in `fail` then that code would execute `do_b` as expected while if `test` resulted in `success` then `do_a` would be executed but if THAT failed then `do_b` would also be executed which may not be what you expected - you could have `sudo... == active` true and still output `NOT running`! Obviously it's unlikely that `echo "Running"` would fail in this case, it's just a general heads up that that's not a safe practice.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks a TON sir for letting me know, I have added a usual if else method in my solution too now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `echo '...'` instead of `apachectl status` which I don't have:

```
$ echo 'Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago' |
    awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'
running
```

That sed commands pipeline in your question has syntax errors and when I try to fix them I just get the output `min ago`:

```
$ echo 'Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago' |
    sed -n '/ago$/p' | sed 's/.\{62\}//'
min ago
```

so idk if this is the output you want from that or not but consider:

```
$ echo 'Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago' |
    awk -F'; ' '{print $NF}'
22min ago
```

I also have chicken.

Answer (score 1):

If `apachectl status` produces `Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago` your problem - getting the string between the first parentheses - can be solved as

```
apachectl status | sed -n 's/[^(]*(\([^()]*\)).*/\1/p'`
```

[Proof](https://tio.run/##HcW7DsIgGAbQV/nSpUCCXJoaxcl3cJOaIJLC4F8j1sl3R@NZzjXU3FqKeUF3jK/yTg7hP9hzJSo0c9RCMeGUV1ht9tJYqUfonbODG7eQejjA2nshhHnp8EFNN0hCX9X5wibBPPvNJ@E53wjljXr0rX0B):

```
echo "Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 08:23:56 -03; 22min ago" | sed -n 's/[^(]*(\([^()]*\)).*/\1/p'
# => running
```

Pattern matches:

```
[^(]*      - from start till first (
(          - ( char
\([^()]*\) - a capturing group matching substring inside parentheses
)          - ) char
.*         - up to the string end
```

`-n ... p` prints the result.